# I repent asking bad questions. Is there a way to check the status or my question-asking privileges?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Last night I was banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Since then, I have read all of the articles linked to in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), gone through and edited all of my questions so as to conform to those suggestions, and I've researched and answered 5 user questions.

I really didn't know that I was asking questions too frequently or that my questions were crappy.  If I had known that my content sucked, I would have fixed it before I got banned.  I really love this site and I want to give back, but I also want to be able to use its services.

Has anyone ever had their ban lifted?  What was that process like?

NOTE: this question is different than the question it is tagged as duplicating, because my question assumes that I have already read all of the information and begun following the advice in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).  That question is merely asking, "WTF?" My question is asking, "World, I screwed up and I am looking to improve.  How do I get feedback on that supposed improvement?"

Comment: "Is there a way to check the status or my question-asking privileges?" Not directly because that could reveal the formula for banning users. You have to look through your profile manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I would say your edits to your questions have been improvements at all, with one possible exception I can see. Most of yours edits were just slight changes in titles or placement of sentences.

Comment: Drink coffee and pray

Comment: You can earn your privileges back by answering questions that are supported by the community (upvoted) and by editing your previous questions and having them reopened if I recall correctly

Comment: Also make sure to check for *deleted* questions. They count against you as well (at least for a while).

Comment: @AndrewBarber  Which edit would would you say was a significant improvement.  I'd like to know so I can improve my other questions in a similar fashion.

Comment: [This is the one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25634804/revisions). For the record; I did not say it was a significant improvement. I just said that I wouldn't say you had improved any of the questions you edited, with that one *possible* exception. It's the only one I saw where you actually added information that seemed relevant.

Comment: @Coffee _"Drink coffee and pray"_ Well, ya know ;-) ...

Comment: @Goodword As for your edit, I simply can't reply other as with [**READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU.**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584).