# Feedback on the quality of this question about a runtime error in a small function I've written

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, question-quality

Here is a link to the post: [Why is this array undefined when I call .length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26549699)

**Note:** I'm *not* asking "why did I get downvoted?"

I was recently banned from asking questions.  Since then, I've really been working hard to write better posts.  This has included reading all of the materials in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revising all of my previous questions to better fit the criteria set out in the help center.

The post I linked to is my first SO question post since my question ban was lifted.  I really tried my utmost to make a clear and generally useful question with [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example code.  I also think I demonstrated prior research by including a link to a similar question and elaboration on why my post is different.

I am very satisfied with the answers that I got.

However, my post got a downvote, which suggests that my understanding of community standards is still not on par with reality.  A comment on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274987/i-am-repenting-is-there-a-way-to-check-the-status-or-my-question-asking-privile) previous Meta post I made on the topic of "better questions," which says "your edits to your questions have[n't] been improvements at all, with one possible exception I can see," corroborates that dissonance between my understanding and reality.

How could I have improved my asking of the question linked to at the top of this post?

The first few comments here make a fair point: it's a pretty basic question.  As soon as I got the answer, it all made sense to me.  But what I am asking is: are there any problems with the *way* I asked the question?

What I am taking away after a handful of comments is that the format of the question is good.  The reason it initially received downvotes is that it's a pretty basic question for most programmers.  As @louis writes: "That you did not know when you asked has no bearing on how the SO crowd is going to respond to your question."

Comment: When you got the answer, did you think "oh.... obviously, I should have passed a value there"?

Comment: Could just be because it's such a simple question. That might not be a *valid* reason to downvote, but people will do it anyway. Following the path that the code would take would have pointed out why `array` is undefined, which should be one of the steps you take in your debugging process for any language, not just javascript.

Comment: The title of your question is wrong.  You wrote "Why is .length is undefined on this array?"  but the actual error from the java interpreter is telling you that the variable named `array` has a value of undefined; it's not an array at all, despite the name.  With a careful reading of the error message you probably could have diagnosed this yourself.

Comment: @DavidGrayson -cough- *javascript* -cough- but yes, the question itself is OK and it pretty much meets the criteria. I think some people don't tolerate debugging questions. This could have been easily solved by reading the error message more carefully, using some `console.log()` or going step by step with the browser debugger.

Comment: @DavidGrayson good point.  But for an inexperienced programmer, that distinction is hard to make...

Comment: The problem I see with that question is not that it is simple but what lesson is being learned with the question and the answer. Is the lesson learned "don't forget to pass arguments to your functions?" If so, then it sits squarely within the realm of typos. There's a difference between not knowing how to pass arguments, and just forgetting to pass them in one instance.

Comment: I don't mean to be defensive just to understand...I didn't know it was a 'typo' question when I asked it.  And in fact, it wasn't a typo, it was a persistent bug.  In the question, I think I very clearly am asking for an *explanation* of the concept causing the bug.  Is there any way I could have made it more clear?

Comment: @Goodword That you did not know when you asked has no bearing on how the SO crowd is going to respond to your question. The issue for voters is not "what the OP honestly thinking so and so?" but "what is the value of this question and the answers to the site?"

Comment: On the other side, you did not receive any close votes! That demonstrates that the question is acceptable, on-topic and meets the criteria to stay alive. Don't take down-votes too personal. People down-vote for any reason they might want and nothing can stop them. You can't please them all.

Comment: It is a well formed question, and a valid one. It's just someone decided they wanted to downvote it. It is a very simple question, and some users may decide that it is "not useful" which is a valid reason to downvote, but not a valid reason to close.

Comment: There's a good chance those are "you're an idiot" downvotes from people jumping straight to your first code snippet.  You call it `list`, but it's an object/dict/lookup that obviously does not have a `length` key.  It's not immediately apparent that that's your _expected output_, and the error is upon trying to _generate_ that, and it took me some rereading to get past the odd choice of variable name

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First off, kudos for trying to improve; and as far as "debugging" questions go; you had a really good one. You included all the code, had a clear problem statement, a model question of the type.

The issue is (and this speaks to why you may have gotten downvotes) not so much that the question is simple, or easy (though granted, those can get negative responses as well) but that getting to the answer requires a skill that every programmer should know, and so just finding your error for you doesn't feel very *useful* (which is actually a downvote reason).

You have basically written the JavaScript equivalent of a `NullReferenceException` (NRE) question. Ask a question about "Why am I getting NRE" in C#, and you will almost always get several downvotes, and an immediate closure as a duplicate of *[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)*.

Note the answers to that question; it tries to teach some basic debugging skills. The answer to your question *really* is, use a debugger, figure out what is null (which you almost already did) and trace it back to the source. In this case, you would have noticed that the passed argument was null, and then noticed that you weren't passing a parameter on the call stack.

Because it's really tedious to type that all the time, and because experienced programmers will be kind of annoyed when asked to simply debug someone else's code, they tend to downvote (which they can, as the comments have mentioned, do for any reason).

It doesn't help your cause that these kinds of errors *are* really common and *very* easy to debug when you know what you are doing (until you get into threads, then all debugging becomes hell).

**TLDR**: Keep it up, and don't get too discouraged by a few downvotes. Also, make sure you have spent significant time debugging before asking an NRE question, and make sure you mention that in the question (include what you know *isn't* causing the error).

Answer (score 6):

The language in the intro paragraph sounds somewhat unclear to me:

> Basically, I want to make an object takes a array and turns it into a list with the following structure

This does not look like a valid sentence structure. If I understand what you mean, it's probably missing a preposition ("object **that** takes an array").

But more importantly, I don't understand the "make an object" part. I admit that I'm not familiar with JavaScript terminology, so I might be missing something there. But in other languages, what you're trying to write is a **function**, not an **object**. And since the code starts with `function`, I suspect it might be the same in JavaScript.

So the following sounds better to me:

> I want to write a function that takes an array as argument, and turns it into a list with the following structure

Apart from that, the question seems reasonably well written. It has the code you tried, the expected result, the actual result (error message). It's clear, on topic, and not too broad.

Beyond that is something that was already mentioned in the comments: The question is very simple. I personally think that simple questions are fine as long as they meet all the criteria on questions (including not being duplicates). But that's somewhat of a disputed point of view, and some people **will** downvote questions that they believe are too simple.

Another aspect that voters might (and arguably should) consider: Does the question/answer have value for future visitors? Is it likely that somebody has the same problem, finds this question, and can profit from the answer? Realistically, I think it's quite unlikely that it will be widely useful.

As always, people are obviously free to vote however they like, and we can only speculate why they voted the way they did. But I believe the above are reasonable guesses.

Comment: haha, embarrassing that there was a "that" typo.  Just fixed it in my post.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, technically, javascript makes `(function() {}) instanceof Object === true`.